How to organise all the data from SEC.Gov Edgar API into instatement and balance sheet
My question in a nutshell:
I am trying to build my own financial data collection python script for stock investing to download company filings data from SEC.Gov. I have develop my script to successfully downloaded data. But I have no idea how to reorganised / group these data organised by a flat list of xbrl elements ( not sure if this is what they are called) back into Income Statement and Balance Sheet and etc.
In details:
I have successfully use python to downloaded all the 10-Q and 10-K filing for a specific ticker (such as AAPL). The data, however are just a flat list of all the items in the Income Statement, Balance Sheets and Cash Flow Statement. Each of these items are "tagged" using us-gaap tag such as Income "RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax" See picture below:

The flat list of "fact" I could get from the Edgar API:

I like to avoid manually mapping these items because I can be wrong and new tags may come in as I download different companies' data. I wonder if there is any comprehensive "industry standard" to map these facts into income statement and etc. I have looked up this fasb.org page to look for the hierarchies for these tags but no luck. I wonder anyone may know where I can, hopefully, find these mapping!
